# Gradle project sync failed in Android Studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, gradle, synchronization

I recently updated my Android Studio from 2.0 to 2.3.3. But when I imported my old projects it started showing Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality will not work properly.

And messages shows:

> Unknown host 'services.gradle.org'. You may need to adjust the proxy setting in Gradle.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Was your computer connected to the net when you tried building?

Comment: No it was not connected.

Comment: Connect to the internet and try again.

Comment: what is your gradle version

Answer (score 4):

Probably this is due to broken download of gradle , I too had this problem :
+ Download the latest gradle zip from : https://services.gradle.org/distributions
+ Extract the folder and replace with the folder in android_studio(where you installed it)/gradle/the_existing_gradle_folder
Hope this helps. Thanks !

Comment: I downloaded the folder, please guide me where do I put it?

Comment: **Go to the folder where you installed Android Studio** (You might have it in C:\Program Files or anywhere you had wished to install,you will find it !). Then, find the **gradle** subfolder there. Extract the folder(from your downloaded zip to this destination.) **Restart** Android Studio ! You are done now !

Comment: If problem persists extract same files in C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\wrapper\dists\<a_random_folder>\apply your extracted folder and your zip file. It's all the broken zip problem...you have a broken downloaded zip file and each time Android studio fetches it, it finds the files but can't open it. That's what generates the error !

Answer (score 0):

Reset all configurations and try again:

Go to..

File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > HTTP Proxy [Under IDE Settings] Enable following option Auto-detect proxy settings

You can also clean project on Build->Clean Project and File->Invalidade Caches/Restart.

If Gradle location is wrong that can also cause this problem. Check on:

File->Setting->Build, Execution, Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle
Under Project level Setting find gradle directory.

Grade Directory is usually C:\Users\username.gradle on windows...

Comment: Thank you. It says the gradle home is wrong. How do I find the correct address?

Comment: I did everything everything you mentioned, but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

These instructions apply to a linux system.
If the issue came after your recent update, then just point Android Studio to the location of gradle it was using before. to do this, go to

```
file  -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment Grade
```

select`Gradle` . On the `Project level settings` select `Use local gradle distribution` and select the folder where gradle was installed. **Be sure to select show hidden folders** (the very last icon) because the gradle folder is hidden.

If you want this to be a global setting, do the same for the `Global Gradle settings`. Set the gradle folder there too. Click apply. and you are done!

[image]